# Function to Perform Complex Transformation in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to do some transformations in my input flatfile. The real problem that i facing here is that my input file consist of 111 Fields .So how could i do the transformation for these many fields.

I have an Option to use UDF's but how could i pass th ose 111 fields to my UDF! Is that possible i.e, Is there is any way that we could pass the entire fields in my tables to my UDF ?

This is my input file

```
A|Adding||Testing|DV005|         |7425478987|10              |     |Jayendran       |                                                  |Arumugam                                          |V|        |MALE|19711028|101         |N|01|               |Candy|               |1312 WEST 10TH STREET                             |                                                  |AUSTIN                                            |TX|                                                  |78703    |840                                               |               |5127768623|               |8009238-12345678912|A|B|H|01500|03000|Chocalates                                            |8009238||RAPID 7 LLC                   |20130501|00000000|               |000|              |               |   |        |        |   |        |        |               |                               |                                |N  |BUS|20150901|20160831|0000000000|0000000001|               |8009238-999940185-002348025-CAR|960230702-CAR-002348025-20150901|Y  |CAR|20160531|20160730|0000000011|0000001321|8009238-999940185-002348025-TRAIN|960230702-TRAIN-002348025-20150901|N  |TRAIN|20150901|20160831|0000000000|0000000000|                                 |                                |N  |VAN|20150901|20160831|               |0000000000|0000000000|                            |                        |               |N  |TRUCK|20150101|20991231|                                 |                                |N  |JEEP|        |        |0000000000|0000000000|                                 |                                |Y  |PLANE|20150901|20160831|               |20160319002530000001
```

Here's my sample output

```
Testing DV005 JayendranArumugam MALE
CAR2016053120160730
TRAIN0000000000000000
VAN0000000000000000
TRUCK0000000000000000
JEEP0000000000000000
PLANE2015090120160831
```

Please help me here to find my solution

Thanks in advance

Jay

Comment: Read http://xyproblem.info/ and ask again. Don't assume anything about the solution. Show a sample of the input data, and the required results. The file volume and number of rows might also be useful.

Comment: Updated my Questions withe sample input and output.In my inputfile i actually use one row which transforms into 7 multiple rows of my output.But in some case it will comes more rows (inputfile),In that case our output will contains multiple of 7 rows corresponding to the each rows from the input file.

Comment: Your input file looks strange. It is not clear if it is a delimited format, fixed width format or a combination(?)

Comment: P.s. The answer you'll get is for the question you ask. what do you mean by "then i will transform it again"?

Comment: My input file is pipeline delimiter i.e, ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

In some Case some fields may not be a values.If any field contains more White spaces it will treat as null/blank values for that corresponding fields

Also Updated my Question by removing the confusing parts.

Comment: The **input file** and **sample output** do not seem to match, e.g. (but not just) `|TRUCK|20150101|20991231|` vs. `TRUCK0000000000000000`

Comment: What Transformation do you want to perform on the column values? it you just want to print the column values in some structured was as you have shown, you can use a combination of existing hive functions or write your own UDF. Multiple columns can be passed into a UDF as well.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz It's because the value of the column before the "TRUCK" column has N.(says No).In that case my output will be TRUCK0000000000000000.

Another case for PLANE the previous value is Y(says yes).so simple Pass through the full values PLANE2015090120160831

In another words we have to Conditionally check  the value before the TRUCK,CAR,PLAN.If it has Y then simple pass through .Else put 0000000000000000

Comment: @Abraham - Yes i would want to print the column in a structured format like Concatination,Splitting,Appending Extra 0's or White Spaces,etc.,

Yes as you said i can write my own UDF. But here's the case where my input has more columns (111) so is it possible to do the transformation for each and every columns in the inputfile without explicitly declaring/defining the whole columns as parameters into my functions.Also its very large to handle

Comment: To the best of my knowledge I don't think you can avoid passing parameters. My suggestion will be to describe the table and get all similar columns that you want to use for your transformation in an excel spreadsheet. Use excel function like "concatenation" to generate the select query with hive functions and conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create external table mytable (rec string)
location '/... put the location here ...'
tblproperties ('serialization.last.column.takes.rest'='true')    
;
```

---

```
select  explode
        (
            array
            (
                concat_ws(' ',f[3],f[4],concat(f[9],f[11]),f[14])
               ,concat(f[ 67] ,case when f[ 66] = 'Y' then concat(f[ 68] ,f[ 69]) else '0000000000000000' end)
               ,concat(f[ 75] ,case when f[ 74] = 'Y' then concat(f[ 76] ,f[ 77]) else '0000000000000000' end)
               ,concat(f[ 83] ,case when f[ 82] = 'Y' then concat(f[ 84] ,f[ 85]) else '0000000000000000' end)
               ,concat(f[ 93] ,case when f[ 92] = 'Y' then concat(f[ 94] ,f[ 95]) else '0000000000000000' end)
               ,concat(f[ 99] ,case when f[ 98] = 'Y' then concat(f[100] ,f[101]) else '0000000000000000' end)
               ,concat(f[107] ,case when f[106] = 'Y' then concat(f[108] ,f[109]) else '0000000000000000' end)
            )
        )

from   (select  split(rec,'\\s*\\|\\s*') as f
        from    mytable
        ) t
;
```

---

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                 col                  |
+--------------------------------------+
| Testing DV005 JayendranArumugam MALE |
| CAR2016053120160730                  |
| TRAIN0000000000000000                |
| VAN0000000000000000                  |
| TRUCK0000000000000000                |
| JEEP0000000000000000                 |
| PLANE2015090120160831                |
+--------------------------------------+
```